# Other ways to do Empty Base Class Optimisation (EBO/EBCO) in modern C++

Tags: c++

The (EBO/EBCO/Empty Base Optimisation) is widely used in STL, but regardless of the implementation differences, the idea seems to be similar: they put EmptyBase and some member into a packed_pair, std::tuple (in implementations where it supports EBCO), or other boost::compressed_pair-look-alikes.

I've found a few links explaining this technique [here](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31473&seqNum=2) and [here](http://www.cantrip.org/emptyopt.html) and they also give this "packing" solution as a good one, and by the look of things the only solution everyone uses.

It all boils down to something like this:

```
template <class EBase>
class SomeClass {
...
    packed_pair<EBase, TElem> pack;
};
```

and then they'll use some getters to get EBase (Allocator/Deleter/...) and the element.
the `pack.first()` and `pack.second()` themselves do not look very attractive, for sure, but otherwise **nice technique, very useful, except for one situation...**

**What if, for example, there's no other member to pack the EmptyBase with?** What if those members are inherited from a class that doesn't need the EmptyBase, so you cannot pack it there, so the question is: what's next? Looks like we need to find another way...

In those articles they quickly dumped the inheritance-based solution as a naive one, but what if we elaborate a little on it?

```
#if (__has_cpp_attribute(no_unique_address) || __cplusplus/100 >= 2020)
// [[no_unique_address]] saves the day, thus an easy case is solved
template <class Base>
class EBO {
public:
    [[no_unique_address]] Base elem;
    EBO(Base const& b) : elem{b} {}

    Base& ebo_unwrap() { return elem; }
};
#else

// Specialising so that we don't inherit from something bad :)
template <class Base, bool Use_inheritance>
class EBO_specialized : public Base {
public:
    EBO_specialized(Base const& b) : Base{b} {}
    Base& ebo_unwrap() { return *static_cast<Base*>(this); }
};

template <class Base>
class EBO_specialized<Base, false> {
public:
    Base elem;
    EBO_specialized(Base const& b) : elem{b} {}

    Base& ebo_unwrap() { return elem; }
};

template <class Base>
class EBO : public EBO_specialized<Base, Type<Base>( is_empty && !is_final )> {
using EBOBase = EBO_specialized<Base, Type<Base>( is_empty && !is_final )>;
public:
    EBO(Base const& d) : EBOBase{d} {}
    using EBOBase::ebo_unwrap;
};
#endif
```

**What are the potential problems that can arise when doing EBO this way?**

let's imagine some use-case now

```
template <class Deleter>
class SomePointer : PointerBase, EBO<Deleter> {
...
using PointerBase::raw_ptr;
~SomePointer() { EBO<Deleter>::ebo_unwrap() (*raw_ptr); }
};
```

Comment: Isn't this the whole reason `[[no_unique_address]]` was standardized?

Comment: Yeah, sure, but we still [sometimes] need to support older versions of C++, or at least compilers other than clang (it has had the [[no_unique_address]] as an extension since C++11

Comment: I think MSVC has the undocumented `msvc::no_unique_address` attribute. Gcc probably has some hidden feature too?

Comment: Hmm... That's interesting, because I couldn't find an MSVC extension for no_unique_address on the web. Don't you by chance have any link?

Comment: Even if undocumented, it's pretty strange I couldn't find any article or blog post considering it, including at least some info on the supported MSVC versions

Comment: It's mentioned [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-cpp20-and-the-std-cpp20-switch/). Don't know if it's enough. Just the first hit on Google

Comment: Aha! Thanks, MSVC did it the other way 'round, for what I understood they postponed optimising [[no_unique_address]] until other ABI-breaks are brought in the next revision and added the msvc::no_unique_address for those ok with that behaviour. But as they stated, it is supported in VS2019 v16.10 and later
And works with /std:c++14 and /std:c++17, and performs optimization. So alas no such thing in earlier versions. Otherwise, very nice indeed)

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. No such thing in earlier versions, that's the whole reason it was standardized. (New language versions actually add new things). Before it was implementation and version dependent. Or, maybe the language even required the empty base class to take some room (1 byte?). I think GCC actually had kind-of a bug, because it had zero-size in the past. But no guarantees over versions.

Comment: The C++ language rules considering object layout demanded sizeof(EmptyClass) == 1, even though it's empty, thus it took some space as a member, regardless of its emptiness, *BUT* the empty base class *could* be (and actually was) optimized size-wise to 0.  So the language did not require empty *base* to be non-zero except for some cases, which are all laid out in standard)

Comment: My question about MSVC was considering the strange use of [[no_unique_address]] which doesn't really optimize anything as of yet vs its msvc:: counterpart that does. And I was mostly interested in compiler support for this feature, given that some project may have older lang.std/compiler version

Comment: Anyway, we got carried away, the original question was about the techniques used to do EBCO, not necessarily (or exclusively) language features that actually render EBCO obsolete because [[no_unique_address]] means no inheritance is needed now but rather the empty member optimization just works without all the bells and whistles, which is awesome, sure, but is slightly outside of the scope of this concrete question.

Comment: By some strange coincidence, I found [this blog](https://www.cppstories.com/2021/no-unique-address/) just now. Maybe still not what you want, but informative.

Comment: @JHBonarius thanks for sharing, that's a very nice blog post, I've read it some time ago when trying to figure out how unique_ptr keeps its size while using allocators) 
I think I'll write an answer to my own question in a few hours, since I've found a few interesting ways, including one truly esoteric (but it seems to be logically sound at least...)

Answer (score 1):

(Some) other ways to do Empty Base Class Optimisation:

1. The easiest one, if you develop for C++20 and beyond or you're using a compiler that provides [[no_unique_address]] as an extension for whatever version of C++ language you're using:

   ```
   template <class Empty>
   class SomeClass {
       [[no_unique_address]] Empty empty; // and that's it!
   };
   ```
2. The most commonly-used one in pre-C++-20 code, seen in places like STL, the "packing" method, also slightly covered both in the question and in the article in comments.
   Pros: It packs an empty base class with another member variable of our class.
   Cons: It packs an empty base class with another member variable of out class! So much syntactic noise...
3. The one proposed in the question:
   (if we drop some #ifdefs switching to [[no_unique_address]] when it's supported, here's what we get: )

   ```
   template <class Base, bool Use_inheritance>
   class EBO_specialized : public Base {
   public:
       EBO_specialized(Base const& b) : Base{b} {}
       constexpr Base& get() { return *static_cast<Base*>(this); }
   };

   template <class Base>
   class EBO_specialized<Base, false> {
   public:
       Base elem;
       EBO_specialized(Base const& b) : elem{b} {}

       constexpr Base& get() { return elem; }
   }; 

   template <class Base>
   class EBO : public EBO_specialized<
       Base, (std::is_empty_v<Base> && !std::is_final_v<Base>)
   > {
   using EBOBase = EBO_specialized<
       Base, (std::is_empty_v<Base> && !std::is_final_v<Base>)
   >;
   public:
       EBO(Base const& d=Base()) : EBOBase{d} {}
       using EBOBase::get;
   };
   ```

   The two articles correctly outline some issues with naive inheritance, i.e. without checking the Base class properties. Those problems are:

   - Base can be `final`. It'd be an error inheriting from it.
   - Base can have virtual functions

   > inheriting from a template parameter can affect whether a member function is virtual.

   Now to our implementation: we explicitly check for emptiness via std::is_empty, which will not be the case for a class containing virtual functions and thus a vptr (in the majority of implementations, in ALL implementations I know of). And the second check for is_final rules out the second possibility.

   Bonus: can be used with constexpr, for example when you'd like to use C++20's constexpr new. Same is true for all above-mentioned techniques.
4. The WTF-way, but admit it, it's nice:)
   [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/4ascMPnb9)

```
    // No inheritance used!
    template <class C, bool IsEmpty=std::is_empty<C>::value>
    struct MaybeEmpty { /* C is empty */
        constexpr MaybeEmpty(C &) noexcept {/* no-op */};
        C& get() { // alas, no constexpr reinterpret_cast
            return *reinterpret_cast<C*>(this);
        }
    };
    
    template <class C>
    struct MaybeEmpty<C,false> { /* C is not empty */
        C obj;
        constexpr MaybeEmpty(C & c) noexcept : obj{c} {}
        constexpr C& get() {
            return obj;
        }
    };
```

Since an empty class has no inner state, we can successfully reinterpret_cast anything into it, so here we reinterpret_cast this, which is a pointer to MaybeEmpty, which is itself empty in this instantiation, so sizeof(MaybeEmpty) == sizeof(Base) == 1(somewhat counterintuitively not 0, due to memory layout rules, but anyway, it's empty).
So, as it uses no inheritance, it doesn't suffer from all of the above-mentioned problems. Except for a new, subtle one: we cannot use constexpr in get().

---

Edit:
4.1.

```
template <class C, bool IsEmpty=std::is_empty<C>::value>
struct MaybeEmpty {
    constexpr MaybeEmpty(C &) noexcept {};
    constexpr C get() {
        union {MaybeEmpty self; C base;} cast{*this};
        return cast.base;
    }
};

template <class C>
struct MaybeEmpty<C,false> {
    C obj;
    constexpr MaybeEmpty(C & c) noexcept : obj{c} {}
    constexpr C get() {
        return obj;
    }
};
```

[godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/K1xKWbG6b)
this works with constexpr in clang & msvc but not gcc > 9.4...

```
P.S. If you've spotted a bug, please write in the comments!
```